# Dynamically changing variables within object dependent on DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, object, memory

I would like to have an object that returns `status` true/false based on the presence of an element in the DOM. I can't get the variable to actually maintain a state other than the state of the loaded page. My last attempt was rather stupid and resulted in `Maximum call stack size exceeded`, which was expected. Any way that I could have these variables change with the DOM?

```
var navigation = function runNav(){
  runNav();
  var navigation = {
    globe : {
      element : $("#icons .globe"),
      status : (function(){
        return ($(".window_stable.globe").length == 1) ? true : false;
      })()
    },
    cart : {
      element : $("#icons .cart"),
      status : (function(){
        return ($(".window_stable.cart").length == 1) ? true : false
      })()
    },
    phone : {
      element : $("#icons .phone"),
      status : (function(){
        return ($(".window_stable.phone").length == 1) ? true : false
      })()
    }
  }
  return navigation;
}();
```

example

```
navigation.cart.status
false
-- Enabled the element
navigation.cart.status
false
($(".window_stable.cart").length == 1) ? true : false
true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you're trying to do. I think you want the function you've defined for `status` to run every time you access the `status` property.

To my knowledge, I don't think you can do it just by making it a property. I think you need to make it a function.

Like this: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFyaB/))

```
var navigation = {
    globe: {
        element: $("#icons .globe"),
        getStatus: function() { return ($(".window_stable.globe").length > 0); }
    },
    cart: {
        element: $("#icons .cart"),
        getStatus: function() { return ($(".window_stable.cart").length > 0); }
    },
    phone: {
        element: $("#icons .phone"),
        getStatus: function() { return ($(".window_stable.phone").length > 0); }
    }
};

alert("status = "+ navigation.cart.getStatus());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the call to `runNav()` at the start of your code. It's causing an infinite recursion loop. Other than that, your code looks fine.

Comment: Are you sure your selectors are correct? You're looking for elements with both the `window_stable` and `phone` class, for example? Also, your values will be set based on when the function is initially created, so if the DOM is not ready yet, you'll probably see `false` all over.

Comment: I posted the output from the console it is clearly the correct selector.

Comment: Then you're probably declaring your function before the DOM is fully loaded. Is your function declaration inside a `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`? Or at least at the bottom of your `<body>`? If not, you're probably just jumping the gun on checking if the elements are present.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are seeing is because the "status" property is being set immediately. So if the navigation object is initialized before these elements are added to the DOM, "status" will always be false.

If you are dead set on accessing "status" like you would a property, you can use the `Object.defineProperty` pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/TFVFS/

```
var navigation = (function runNav(){
    var navigation = {
        globe : {
            element : $("#icons .globe")
        },
        cart : {
            element : $("#icons .cart")
        },
        phone : {
            element : $("#icons .phone")
        }
    };

    Object.defineProperty(navigation.globe, "status", {
        get:function(){return $(".window_stable.globe").length == 1 ? true : false;}   
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigation.cart, "status", {
        get:function(){return $(".window_stable.cart").length == 1 ? true : false;}   
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigation.phone, "status", {
        get:function(){return $(".window_stable.phone").length == 1 ? true : false;}   
    });
    return navigation;
})();

console.log(navigation.cart.status);
console.log(navigation.globe.status); 
console.log(navigation.phone.status);
```

This isn't fully backwards compatible, and isn't fully supported in IE prior to version 9.

@Travesty3's answer will be backwards compatible, but it requires a change in syntax. Personally, I would recommend his answer if you need to support version of IE before 9.